# Symfony 5.3 - FormBuilder RepeatedType - Error message is not shown in form when password not the same

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5, symfony-validator

I have a form with a RepeatedTyp for the password.

```
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'label' => 'form.register.password.label',
            'label_attr' => ['class' => 'text-blue'],
            'invalid_message' => 'The passwords do not match!',
            'first_options' => [
                'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'form.register.password.opt1.placeholder', 'class' => 'form-control']
            ],
            'second_options' => [
                'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'form.register.password.opt2.placeholder', 'class' => 'mt-1 form-control']]
        ])
```

In Twig it looks like this:

```
{{ form_label(register.password) }}<span class="text-danger">*</span><br>
{{ form_widget(register.password.first) }}<br>
{{ form_widget(register.password.second) }}
```

If I enter two different values for the passwords and submit the form, I see in the profiler toolbar the error message, but it's not shown in the form itself.

In the Symfony documentation is stated that "If the two fields don't match, an error will be shown to the user".
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#validation

What do I have to do, so the message is shown or better, what am I doing wrong?

Help is really appreciated!

Many thanks!

Markus

Answer (score 1):

Okay, looks like I am just to tired.

Forgot {{ form_errors(register.password) }}

Sorry for that.